# Wordpress Mini Cart auto qty update not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, minicart

I am facing an error ajax load in the Woocommerce Mini cart qty + - Not refresh price when I clicking + -

My WordPress version 5.4.1 and Woocommerce Version 4.1.1

My mini-cart.php code is below :
Please help what I did wrong it's custom mini-cart.php I have created, thanks in advance, I really appreciate if anyone can help me

My website URL:https://wmiserver.com/bulkwholesale/

```
<?php
/**
 * Mini-cart
 *
 * Contains the markup for the mini-cart, used by the cart widget.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>
<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>
    <div class="widget_shopping_cart_body kapee-scroll">
        <div class="kapee-scroll-content">
            <div class="cart-countdown-empty">
          <?php echo do_shortcode('[checkout_countdown]');?>
          </div>
            <ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo esc_attr( $args['list_class'] ); ?>">
                <?php
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );

                    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                        $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                            $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                            <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                    echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                        'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                        sprintf(
                                            '<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>',
                                            esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                            esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'kapee' ),
                                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                            esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                        ),
                                        $cart_item_key
                                    );
                                ?>
                                <?php if ( empty( $product_permalink ) ) : ?>
                                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <a class="mini_cart_item_image" href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="mini-cart-item-content">
                                    <?php if ( empty( $product_permalink ) ) : ?>
                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_name ); ?>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <a class="mini_cart_item_image" href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                                            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_name ); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                            <? echo do_shortcode('[quantity_minicart]');?>
                                </div>
                            </li>



                <?      }
                    }
?>
<div class="minicart-upsell">
<div class="upsell-tittle">
<span>Boost your results with:</span>
</div>

<?
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
$product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
$product = new WC_Product($_product );
    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();
   if ($upsells){
$meta_query = WC()-> query -> get_meta_query( $meta_query, $main_query );
    $args = array(
        'status'=>'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'no_found_rows' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'post__in' => $upsells,
        'post__not_in' => array($product-> get_id() ),
        'meta_query' =>array($meta_query),
    );

 $products = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

<?php wc_get_template_part( 'cart/upsell', 'product' ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif;
}}
?>
</div>
<?
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents' );
                ?>
            </ul><div class="mini-cart-footer-block"><?php echo do_shortcode('[sc name="cart-icon-box"]'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="widget_shopping_cart_footer">
        <div class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total">
            <?php
            /**
             * Woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_subtotal - 10
             */
             ?><div class="saving"><? echo do_shortcode('[mini_cart_discount]');?></div> 
        <div class="subtotal"><?    do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total' );
            ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' ); ?></p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_after_buttons' ); ?>

    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-mini-cart-empty">
        <i class="cart-empty-icon"></i>
        <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message"><?php esc_html_e( 'No products in the cart.', 'kapee' ); ?></p> 
        <?php do_action( 'kapee_after_empty_mini_cart' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```